# How to order someone to want something?

Tags: classical-latin, phrase-request, imperative

I asked yesterday [about the imperative of *velle*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2369/79), and it turned out that does not really have an imperative.
If the most obvious option is not available, how should I give an order to want?
A phrase or two with a classical use example would be great.
It can be just an imperative if that is the idiomatic choice, but I do not know which verb to pick if *velle* is not available.

A use example was given in the linked question, but I will give another one here.
In the following case I would like use the imperative of *velle*:

> Do you want to build a welfare state?
>   Want to share!

The point is that willingness to share is the key to a welfare state, more so than sharing itself.
I do not mean that I really think this way; this is just to give an example situation where one might want to order someone to want something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not been able to find any attested forms of an imperative for *velle* (see linked question) or *cupio* (*cupi, cupite, cupito, cupitote*).

Expanding to other synonyms, though, you quickly find alternatives that preserve the structure (and perhaps strangeness) of your example sentence.

1. ***desiderare***

> Quid ergo est? Vide quomodo quisque illorum tulerit et, si fortes fuerunt, ipsorum illos animo **desidera**. (Seneca iunior, *Dialogi* 9.16.2.2)
>
> *See how each of them endured his fate, and if they endured it bravely, long in your heart for courage as great as theirs.*

(I'm a little confused by the syntax of *ipsorum illos*: this is a public-domain translation.)

> Liberi atque incolumes **desiderate** patriam; immo desiderate, dum patria est, dum ciues eius estis. (Livius, *Ab Urbe Condita* 22.60.15.1)
>
> *Long for your country, you who are free and unharmed; indeed, long for it, while it is still your country, while you are still its citizens.*

Note that *desidero* can take a noun or AcI, but not a standalone infinitive.

2. ***optare***

> Huc ergo cogitationes tuae tendant, hoc cura, **hoc opta**, omnia alia vota deo remissurus, ut contentus sis temet ipso et ex te nascentibus bonis. (Seneca iunior, *Epistulae Morales ad Lucilium* 20.8.2)
>
> *Let your thoughts attend only to this, care and **wish for this one thing**, consigning all other desires to god, that you be content with your own self and the good things that bring about.

This imperative usage of *optare* is relatively common, but also does not take the infinitive.

In light of this, one possible translation of your sentence is:

> **Hoc opta(te), ut compartiatur!**

Answer (score 4):

That case is weird. If you want to build a welfare state, you do not need to *want* to share, but only *to share*. Depending on the author, you'd see either an indirect command or hortatory subjunctive urging them to share, or even an if-clause:

> If you want to build a welfare state, it is necessary to share.

If you absolutely needed an imperative here, there are several you could use (from the LSJ):

- *desiderare* "to long for, greatly wish for, to desire something not possessed" (the LSJ entry lists more synonyms, too, if you want to go around digging);
- *optare* "to choose or select" - sense in "choose to do something" = "want to do something"
- *gestire* "Transf., to desire eagerly or passionately, to long for"

All three can take a complementary infinitive, which should satisfy your example, though an *ut* clause is more normal.

Comment: The example was not perfect, but the point was that someone might want to give an order to want. I tried to clarify the question a bit. Are all of these verbs used with an infinitive like *sic facere desiderate/cupite/gestite*?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Typically they would take an *ut* clause.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer *tibi oportet communicare*, without using *velle*: 'it behoves you to share'. Or you could instead use the gerundive of velle (if you accept its existence, which I'm personally a bit doubtful of): *Communicare est tibi volendum.*

Comment: I like these suggestions. I am not sure if *volendum* is attested, but it is easy enough to understand if one is willing to depart from classical style. Thanks!