# How did velle give rise to vel?

Tags: etymology, verbs, conjunction

Some time ago I asked [about the missing imperative of *velle*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2369/79).
The answer indicated an old imperative (or indicative) second person singular form, *vel*, and that this word became a conjunction.
I am familiar with the verb *velle* and conjunction *vel*, but the connection between them is not entirely clear.
(It had never even occurred to me that the two words might be related.)

Could someone explain how *velle* gave rise to *vel*?
What benefit is there in viewing *vel* as a verb form?
I am not sure if I can formulate a sensible question, but I would like to understand the relation between *velle* and *vel* better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The interpretation of the origin of *vel* from a second person indicative of *volo* is proved by the comparison with the Umbrian "heris - heris",  2. pers. from *herio = *volo* (Hofmann – Szantyr p. 501). You can compare even the modern Greek "θέλεις - θέλεις" or the Italian "vuoi - vuoi", which have the same meaning of the second person indicative of *volo* and in that case could be translated with "either - or" (Thumb, p. 173).

The origin from an old imperative of *volo* is formally and semantically impossible (Jacobsohn, p. 344), and it is more likely that the form "vel" derives from *vell < *vels due to proclisis (Jacobsohn, p. 348). For other hypothesis, see Walde – Hoffmann p. 743.

The semantic development started from an **interrogative** form
("do you want?" "if you want"):

> Plaut. *Aul.* 452: *etiam intro duce, si vis, vel gregem venalium*
>
> Cic. *Planc.* 79: *agitur studium tuum vel
>   etiam, si vis, existimatio, laus aedilitatis*
>
> Cic. *Tusc.* 3,18: *qui sit frugi igitur vel, si mavis, moderatus et temperans*
>
> Catull. 55,21: *vel, si vis, licet obseres palatum*

Then it became gradually widespread into the **disjunctive** form ("or if you want", "if you prefer"):

> Plaut. *Pseud.* 31: *lege vel tabellas redde*
>
> Plaut. *Poen.* 1382: *utrum vis est, vel leno vel Lycus*

His connection with *volo* is thus expressed by the possibility of choice between the two terms.

Bibliography:

J.B. Hofmann – A. Szantyr, *Lateinische Syntax und Stilistik*, München 1972.

H. Jacobsohn, *Got. Ōgs, Lat. Vel*, "KZ" 45, 1913, pp. 342-348.

A. Thumb, *Handbuch der neugriechischen Volkssprache*, Straßburg 1910.

A. Walde – J.B. Hoffmann, *Lateinisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch*, II, Heidelberg, 1954.