# What does "noli" really mean?

Tags: imperative

I understand *nolle* to be short for *non volle,* i.e. "not to wish/want".

I thought *noli* was the imperative form of this: *non vo—*er, wait a minute, [volo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/volo#Latin) has no imperative!

So, what's *noli?* The usual explanation is that it literally means "Be unwilling", but what about the missing *voli?*

Comment: Curiously, *nōlī* has been semantically bleached to the point that *nōlī velle* is attested for the actual "be unwilling" meaning.

Comment: And even more curiously, the only "imperative" uses I've found use the second person subjunctive *velīs* rather than *_volī_…

Comment: Related question: [What is the imperative of velle?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2369/79)

Comment: "nōlī velle" would be redundant, like "non veli velle".

Answer (score 3):

I suppose in all the dictionaries it appears:

Noli: Imperative present of nolo.

Nolle: Infinitive present of nolo .

Nolo: (...) Noli is used as an imperative in prohibitions (with similar words).

It is necessary to consider that there are "twist idiomatic" in the expressions of:

- Implore.
- Order.
- Prohibition.

These forms are usually addressed in the grammar books in the sections dedicated to the imperative.

Noli is one of the 4 "twist idiomatic" used in classical literature:
Noli (nolite) + infinitive: noli (nolite) facere, do not do it. It was (and must be considered) a courteous prohibition, do not want, do not want to do, in which the imperative of nolo softens the negative order. The use made forget that primitive nuance of courtesy.

- The most frequent turn is: Cicero: nolite existumare, do not go to believe. Noli putare, do not think.
- In poetry developed an analogical spin: parce + infinitive. Parce timere, do not be afraid.

Other forms of classical prose ban (summary):

- Ne (cave) + perfect subjunctive.
- Ne (cave) + present subjunctive.
- Ne + imperative.

In addition, it would be necessary to take into account the imperfect and pluscuamperfect of subjunctive that reflect order or prohibition to the past, that is, what someone would have wanted someone to do or not in a given circumstance: faceres, to have done; fecisset, that would have done.

The forms of imperative of volo are realized by those of nolo, in fact nolo is especially frequent in imperative, see usage notes of nolo:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nolo#Latin

Answer (score -2):

I've found that:

> Nolo (non-volo)
>   Non vis (rarer nevis)
>   Non vult
>   Nolit (non velit)
>   Nolim (non velim)
>   Nolis (non velis)
>   Nolumus (non volumus)
>   Nolimus (non volimus)
>   Non vultis
>   Nolitis (non velitis)
>   Nolunt (non volunt)
>   Nolint (non velint)
>
> Imperative forms: noli (sing.)/nolite (plur.)

*Source: Latin, an intensive course (De Floyd L. Moreland, Rita M. Fleischer)*

According to this book "nolo", for instance, is used for "non volo", in assertive sentences, but they don't tell us whether the contraction is mandatory. (It seems to be?)

Considering the pattern, for instance "**no**n ve**lint**" = Nolint:

1. They removed the final "n" of "non", to keep "no".
2. They removed the first syllabe "ve" from "velint".
3. Very short words don't contract (non vis).
4. Some other words don't contract, we don't know why (Non vultis, and not Notis)

When it's "volunt", they do the same, they remove the first syllabe "vo".
Nolle would be Non+velle.

So, if this pattern is regular, "noli" would be a contraction of "non veli", and "nolite" of "non velite".
I've found occurrences of them in texts.
.

Comment: You've found occurrences of "nōn velī" and "nōn velīte" in texts? Don't leave us on a cliff-hanger, share them! Also, you should correct your explanation: *nōlō*, *nōlint* etc are of course contractions of *nevolō*, *nevelint* (you even cite *nevīs*). *Nōn* cannot contract - not only that, it was one syllable longer at the time all of these were formed.

Comment: I won't correct the explanation because it's not mine: I've only pasted the book content, as it is. I didn't say I've found "non veli", but considering the pattern given by this book, that is always the same, it's a valid hypothesis.

Comment: Some books chose to use "non volo" and some books say it's "ne volo". Maybe older books chose one and more recent ones chose the other way, it's something that should be studied. If a book consider "ne-volo" (both explanations are common, and nobody agrees on the best one) If the "ne veli" is chosen, unlike in this book, the explanation simply has to be turned in "ne veli" instead of "non veli", it's simple.I'm not sure we could find more "ne veli" than "non veli", it seems to be very ancient forms of mandatory contractions.

Comment: So... what did you "find occurrences of them in texts"? Is the part about "they removed etc" really from that book? Are you sure the books that give nōlō = nōn volō talk about etymology and not simple equivalence in meaning? *Nevelī* doesn't occur - it's been contracted into *nōlī*. *Nē velīs* occurs meaning "ut nōn velīs" and is never contracted. Perhaps then you could mention in the answer itself what you just mentioned to me about the different treatment by different books.

Comment: I think it's clear, because I don't see how I can format it to make it more clear. I quoted that is from the book, and enclosed  the quote in a colored frame, and it's close by the line: "source:...." and the next line is "According to this book"... If I find another book explaining in a different way, I will paste it.

Comment: It's not clear at all that there are two points of view on this - you make no mention of the *ne-volō* derivation. Anyway, could you finally explain what occurrences you've found in texts?